# Register using phone number

Tags: android, authentication, server

How is it possible to make an Android application and before entering the application, the user needs to input his/hers phone number in order to login. After entering their phone number, the user receives a message with an activation code or a call like for e.g Viber or Whatsapp works.
I already know how to make a Login/Register using email, password but I am not sure how can the user receive a message with activation code and that it works with phone number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a service like Twillio or Voxeo. Those are not the only two. There are many services like that. I am not recommending a particular one.

Comment: find this link it might be useful http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-adding-sms-verification-like-whatsapp-part-1/

Comment: as @StephanBranczyk said when user enters phone number on click of register call one of above service which will send message in parallel to taking user to verification screen... once message comes to cell use broadcast receiver to read message and populate that in verfication screen

Comment: You can use firebase as well.It was easier for me.Here is the reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth It might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Twilio for this purpose

Call the following calss in a background thread

```
public class TwilioTest {

    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    public TwilioTest(String number, String code) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACec5a3465a111443de55a79a47b22f4b5/SMS/Messages");
        String base64EncodedCredentials = "Basic "
                + Base64.encodeToString(
                        (ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + AUTH_TOKEN).getBytes(),
                        Base64.NO_WRAP);

        httppost.setHeader("Authorization", base64EncodedCredentials);
        try {

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+12568011137"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", number));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body",
                    "Welcome to demo app. Your OTP is " + code));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            System.out.println("Entity post is: "
                    + EntityUtils.toString(entity));

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
```

You need to generate a random code
The above class has constructor which accepts number and the four digit code.

You can call it in the following way

```
ProgressDialog dialog;
dialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Sending Message");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                                    dialog.cancel();

                                };

                                @Override
                                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    new TwilioTest(number, randomCode);
                                    return null;
                                }

                                protected void onPreExecute() {

                                    dialog.show();
                                };
                            }.execute();
```

You can compare the code sent and entered once this is done.